# Is there a way to re-tighten a minifigure's hip joint?

Tags: minifigures, repair

When a minifigure is new, the joints where its legs joins its hips is relatively stiff. However, when a minifig gets old and has been used a lot, this joint can get very loose leaving its legs very floppy. Why does this happen? Is there a risk-free way to re-tighten this joint?

Comment: Older minifig legs had looser joints, since then minifigs have been stiffened so legs will stay in place when moved.

Comment: @Ambo100: When did LEGO make the change? I have a minifig on my keychain, and his legs are *really* floppy. I don't *think* I've had him more than a couple of years.

Comment: @Kramii if it's a keychain there's a good chance it's been made in china - check if there are rectangular cutouts under the arms. Plus, keychains are partially glued anyway, so just glue the legs as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would try pulling off the legs and dropping a tiny, tiny amount of plastic glue on the hinge, smooth it out and let it dry, then put the leg back on.  It should provide enough friction to the leg again so they aren't so loose.

Answer (score 2):

This video has a pretty good method: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rEkVPVgonRk

If you don't want to watch:

1. Pop both legs off the hips.
2. Rip off a small square of paper, preferably tissue paper.
3. Place it over the hole in one of the legs.
4. With the paper still around it, forcibly snap the leg back into place.
5. Repeat for the other leg.
6. Rip off any excess paper that is around the minifig.
7. If the legs get loose again, repeat steps one through six.